Log4j2 asyncLogger missing log events in application log files
I am using Log4j2's AsyncLogger in my Java application, which is deployed on a Kubernetes environment. The application is also configured with the New Relic Java agent, and I can see log events arriving in New Relic. However, I've noticed that some log events are randomly missing from my application log files.
My Understanding:

The AsyncLogger uses a RingBuffer to handle log events    asynchronously.
Application thread pushes messages in the RingBuffer. When the RingBuffer becomes full, new log events bypass the buffer    and are sent directly to the appenders, such as    FileAppender.
The AsyncLogger thread responsible for processing the    RingBuffer    does not catch up fast enough to empty the buffer,    resulting in    some events remaining unprocessed in the buffer.
Due to    Kubernetes' nature of recreating and terminating pods, any    unprocessed log events in the RingBuffer during a pod termination are    lost, leading to permanent log loss.

My Question:
Is my understanding correct that if the RingBuffer of the AsyncLogger becomes full and some events remain unprocessed, those events are lost when the pod will be destroyed or restarted by Kubernetes?
Additional Context:
My application logs are managed using AsyncLogger and appenders configured in log4j2.xml.
The environment is set up on Kubernetes, which periodically scales pods up and down or restarts them, potentially causing unprocessed events to be lost.
Spring Boot: 2.7.12
Any insights or best practices to prevent log loss in such scenarios would be greatly appreciated.
log4j2.xml excerpt
<RollingFile name="RollingFileAppenderFunnel" fileName="${log-path}/ride_flow.log"
                 filePattern="${archive-path}/ride_flow-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
        <JsonLayout  compact="true" eventEol="true" properties="true" stacktraceAsString="true" objectMessageAsJsonObject="true" >
            <KeyValuePair key="@timestamp" value="$${date:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}"/>
        </JsonLayout>
        <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
    </RollingFile>

    <AsyncLogger name="com.jeeny.pay.funnel" level="info" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFileAppenderFunnel"/>
    </AsyncLogger>


@Remko Popma, can you please respond?

Are you able to pinpoint the log events that are missing? If the shutdown log events are missing, there might be a problem with the shutdown order. Spring Boot should shutdown the logging system at the right time, but Log4j Core might do it too (see log4j2.shutdownHookEnabled).

AsyncLogger does not work well with slow consumers... I would recommend not using AsyncLogger in your case.

ok, does my understanding make sense as to why some logs are being missed?

Will not using AsyncLogging impact performance? In my case, what about synchronous logger with async appender?

@MuhammadAbuBakr: asynchronous components do not necessarily provide the best performance (see Log4j Core for performance). It all depends on the profile of your application and the characteristics of your appenders. Asyn components generally provide a lower latency on the logging thread, unless the queue is full.

@PiotrP.Karwasz, mine is a Spring Boot application having RestControllers so there will be multiple threads writing in the same file. Using synchronous logging will cause blocking. Asynchronous logging will possibly lose logs. I am in a bit of quagmire here.
